# Removing duplicates from a dropdown list with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a dynamic dropdown list from a database which I'd want to remove duplicates from a row so it doesn't multiple values in the list. The field I'm trying to put in the dropdown is District

JS

```
.controller('send_msg_district_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$location){

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/Admin/calls/app_users.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.district=data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
        })

.filter("removeDups", function(){
  return function(data) {
    if(angular.isArray(data)) {
      var result = [];
      var key = {};
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var val = data[i];
        if(angular.isUndefined(key[val])) {
          key[val] = val;
          result.push(val);
        }
      }
      if(result.length > 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="item.District" ng-options="option for option in district | removeDups">
    <option value="" disabled>
        Please select an option
    </option>
</select>
```

When I click on the dropdown I get `[object object]`

Comment: any reason you have "option for option..." instead of just `option in district | removeDups`?

Comment: Removing the dupes in the success function is the more appropriate location for this type of logic.. or on the server.

Comment: Is district an array of objects or simple array (of string elements)? Do give district array

Comment: Array of objects

Answer (score 0):

if district is an array of objects, you have to use `ng-options` in an other way.
You see `[object object]` in your dropdown, because you set it like this.

i'm pretty sure your objects have a title-value or something like this?
in this case you have to use:

```
<select ng-model="item.District" ng-options="option as option.title for option in district | removeDups">
    [...]
</select>
```